# Overriding Material-UI styles via theme 'overrides' configuration, styling a NotchedOutline

Tags: material-ui, jss

I have a [Code Sandbox repro here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-p371r).

Ordinarily, a `TextField`, which is a convenience wrapper of several other components, has its border color as a plain grey, and the hover color as  `theme.palette.primary.main`.

I want to change this, to make both the hover and non-hover color the same.

I've been trying this with the overrides configuration:

```
const themeOptions = {
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#FF5555"
    },
    text: {
      primary: "#5555FF"
    }
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      root: {
        borderColor: "#55FF55",
        "&:hover": {
          borderColor: "#55FF55"
        }
      },
      notchedOutline: {
        borderColor: "#55FF55",
        "&:hover": {
          borderColor: "#55FF55"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The problem I have is that the class that gets applied to the the `fieldset` that ultimately gets styled is:

`.MuiOutlinedInput-root:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline`

How do I change this rule with the overrides config?

That is, I can override either `MuiOutlinedInput-root:hover` or `.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline` ok, but how do I do override it for the combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `notchedOutline` property in the `overrides` section, you could remove the "&:hover" property and add the `notchedOutline` in the root hover section like this:

```
overrides: {
  MuiOutlinedInput: {
    root: {
      borderColor: "#55FF55",
      "&:hover $notchedOutline": {
        borderColor: "#55FF55"
      }
    },
    notchedOutline: {
      borderColor: "#55FF55"
    }
  }
}
```

This way the hover and the default root color will be the same.